# Change connectivity mode from MTP to MCS

Tags: android, adb

Is there a way to change the USB connectivity mode from MTP to MCS using `adb` commands?

Comment: Related: http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/120026/how-do-i-change-from-ptp-to-mtp-mode-cannot-find-options-in-settings

Change your device mode, then see its programmatic value: `adb shell getprop sys.usb.config`

Set your device mode with values like: `adb shell setprop sys.usb.config "mtp,adb"`

Comment: @y3sh, AndroidEnthusiasts are notoriously bad at giving proper attributions. Why did you think it was a good idea to link to a regurgitated version of the already posted answer down below?

Comment: @AlexP. while your answer is correct, it is hard to parse. I had the same question the OP did, but your answer didn't have enough information for me. Without knowledge of `setprop` and accessing it via `shell`, I had to look elsewhere. I found what I was looking for in the related post, and figured I could save others the trip.

Answer (score 1):

In android the USB driver is controlled by `/sys/class/android_usb/android0/functions` sysfs file. You could either write to it directly or set system `sys.usb.config` property or use `svc usb setFunction` java wrapper.

To get the list of proper names for USB functions supported by your specific device do `grep usb.config= /init*rc`

Alternatively, change the connectivity mode manually via UI and then write down the value of `getprop sys.usb.config`. Do that for all modes you want to switch between.